# Are there models of mortality due to sea level increases (via climate change)?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level

In a [self-answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/45056/29579) of mine on Skeptics, one of the comments rightly pointed out that the model in question (from Impact Lab) does not explicitly account for mortality due to sea level changes. Are there such models published which model mortality changes due to sea level changes?

(Also is there a tag here for economic or social aspects of climate change or earth sciences other than geology?)

And I don't mean [coral mortality](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.marpolbul.2014.03.058) (or other animals), but human...

Comment: My thought is that mortality due to sea level rise may not have been considered by most modelers probably because sea level rise will not be instantaneous but protracted. Consequently, the expectation is that humans & most land animals will migrate to higher ground. One aspect of this is how would mortality be measured? Currently some Pacific islands are already experiencing sea inundation, affecting their fresh water supplies. If a coconut tree becomes so loose that it falls & kills someone due to water dislodgement, is that to be considered & how should that be modeled?